# can we highlight the particular value on row chart by dimension filtering?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

[image]

how can we highlight the particular value on dimension filtering like below image and (phoenix) should come on the top.
any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  dc.js already greys out the other bars and leaves the selected one colored, although you could add a CSS rule for `.dc-chart g.row .selected` if you want it to appear different.  I don't think you can rearrange the bars in response to filtering, without some serious hacking.

Answer (score 0):

i'm able to highlight the particular value by doing **chart.filter('phoenix');** after dimension filtering .but unable to re-arrange that bars.